# JUnit Mockito mock one method in another class Error

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I use Netbeans 8.1 , Junit and Mockito to write unit test for my project.
Here is some pieces of my code

To be tested function:

```
public Map<String, String> getAllUsers() {

    if (allUsers == null) {
        if (session.checkACL2("DonateBookPrivilegeLevel") || session.checkACL2("ManageUserPrivilegeLevel")) {
            Iterator<User> it = userFc.findAll().iterator();
            System.out.println("PC::enum()");
            allUsers  = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                User item = it.next();
                allUsers.put(item.getName(), item.getUserId().toString());
            }
        }
    }
    return allUsers;
}
```

My Test class:

```
package com.controller;

import com.entities.User;
import com.jsfc.util.JsfUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyObject;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonalCenterControllerTest {

    public PersonalCenterControllerTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }  

    /**
     * Test of getAllUsers method, of class PersonalCenterController.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("getAllUsers");

        PersonalCenterController pcController = new PersonalCenterController();

        SessionController session = Mockito.mock(SessionController.class);

        when(session.checkACL2(anyString())).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true);

        Map<String,String> userMap = null;
        userMap = pcController.getAllUsers();

    } 
}
```

As you can see, I call session.checkACL2() which is defined in another class, I use [Using Mockito to mock a class method inside another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596913/using-mockito-to-mock-a-class-method-inside-another-class) to fix

```
SessionController session = Mockito.mock(SessionController.class);
doReturn(true).when(session).checkACL2((String) anyObject());
```

but it calls `NullPointerException` at if line.

Comment: Which Junit runner are you using ? Have you annotated your class using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or something similar ? Can you post your complete class including import statements? You may remove other functions that are not applicable.

Comment: I use Netbeans integrated junit 4.12. I forgot to add @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) before, but after I add it, it still shows Error: caused an Error : java.lang.NullPointerException . And When I go to Source, it still stuck at session.checkACL2()

Comment: You don't need thenReturn twice. Can you paste the NullPointerException stack trace ?

Comment: I found out the problem, you can see Andrey Bardyshev's answer. The NullPointerException is caused because I didn't set my mock `SessionController` instance to `PersonalCenterController` instance. Thanks.

Comment: You can alternatively do mockStatic so all instances of SessionController will take the behaviour you defined so you don't have to pass the object to your controller. However, passing explicitly is the better and right way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually passing mocked `SessionController` instance to your `PersonalCenterController` instance?
If you try calling `SessionController` methods right after mocking does it return what you expected?

```
SessionController session = Mockito.mock(SessionController.class);
when(session.checkACL2(anyString())).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true);
assertTrue(session.checkACL2("DonateBookPrivilegeLevel"));
assertTrue(session.checkACL2("ManageUserPrivilegeLevel");
```

As I see `NullPointerException` here could be from `session` instance either being `null` or returning `null`, that is then being converted to `boolean`. My first step would be to figure out which is it.

Comment: I found out this problem, but as you can see in the to-be-tested function, session is a private member variable. If I want to set my mock session instance to PersonalCenterController instance, I must call another method in the class setSession(), is it right to call another function when I test one function?

Comment: If you have a simple setter `setSession()` with no additional behaviour then I think it's perfectly fine. If you have some complex logic inside  `setSession()` but you have covered this logic with other tests I think it's also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your JUnit with 'MockitoJUnitRunner.class'.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest{

public void myMethodTest(){
   SessionController session = Mockito.mock(SessionController.class);
 Mockito.when(session).checkACL2(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true);
  //Write logic to test your businesss logic inside class and assert the result.
}

}
```

Comment: I add @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) before my Test but it still shows Error: caused an Error : java.lang.NullPointerException . And When I  go to Source, it still stuck at session.checkACL2()